# Git credential core.askpass

Tags: git

In our CI/CD script I found this command at the the beginning

```
git -c core.askpass=true reset --hard
```

I know it's related to git credential but what does it really means ?

Comment: It looks like the config property core.askpass is being overridden for this one command? https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials

Comment: @evolutionxbox But why?! `git reset --hard` doesn't require any credentials, it's a completely local operation.

Comment: @phd beats me. I really don’t understand why either.

Comment: Are you perhaps using Git LFS or partial clone?  Those are the only situations I can think of where a network request might occur as the result of a `git reset --hard`.